Can we publish a topic to another ROS_DOMAIN_ID?
Let's say ROS_DOMAIN_ID of my computer is 5 and my robot's 10.
My question is there any way to publish cmd_vel message from my computer to my robot without changing the ROS_DOMAIN_ID?
And I want to do this from my C++ code.

The ROS_DOMAIN_ID is provided to isolate systems. The purpose of it is that nodes with different IDs set will not interact. So in general they are designed to not interact.
You don't share information motivating your request so I think this is an X-Y problem.
ROS_DOMAIN_ID is set in each environment and doesn't need to be the same for all nodes run on the same computer. Aka if you just want to run a teleportation node on your computer that node could be run with id 10 in isolation from your computer's other nodes.
If what you're asking is about bridging two separate systems, the first question is why don't you run them on the same ROS_DOMAIN_ID? There are potential reasons, but in general using different namespaces with the same ROS_DOMAIN_ID is the recommended default way to isolate nodes.
If you have a need to connect two different ROS_DOMAIN_ID systems you can write a very specific node that talks to both ROS_DOMAIN_ID s by manually initializing the ROS_DOMAIN_ID for a second context instead of letting it use the default initialization from the environment variable. And then internally pass the data between the node instances.
